# React useEffect not running after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am querying Firebase real time database, saving the result into state and then rendering the results.

My data is not displaying because the page is rendering before the data is had. What I don't understand is why

```
useEffect(() => {
    for (var key in projects) {
      var projectData = {
        title: projects[key].title,
        description: projects[key].description,
      };
      result.push(<Project props={projectData} />);
    }
   }, [projects]);
```

My use effect is not running once the projects state change is triggered, populating the array and triggering the conditional render line.

What am I missing here?

```
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState();
  const { user } = useUserAuth();
  const result = [];
  const dbRef = ref(db, `/${user.uid}/projects/`);

  useEffect(() => {
    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      setProjects(snapshot.val());
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (var key in projects) {
      var projectData = {
        title: projects[key].title,
        description: projects[key].description,
      };
      result.push(<Project props={projectData} />);
    }
  }, [projects]);

  return (
    <>
      {result.length > 0 && result}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` should also be a state!

Right now at every rerender `result` is being set to `[]`. So when the useEffect does kick in, the subsequent rerender would set `result` to `[]` again.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a `useEffect`. Effects run *after* rendering, but you're trying to put `<Project>` elements on the page, which must happen *during* rendering. Simply do it in the body of your component:

```
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState();
  const { user } = useUserAuth();
  const dbRef = ref(db, `/${user.uid}/projects/`);

  useEffect(() => {
    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      setProjects(snapshot.val());
    });
  }, []);

  const result = [];
  for (var key in projects) {
    var projectData = {
      title: projects[key].title,
      description: projects[key].description,
    };
    result.push(<Project props={projectData} />);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {result.length > 0 && result}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

`result.push` does not mutate `result` in place. It instead creates a copy of the array with the new value.

As a solution, you *could* get your current code working by hoisting `result` into a state variable like so:

```
const [result, setResult] useState([])
...
 useEffect(() => {
    for (var key in projects) {
      ...
      setResult([...result, <Project props={projectData} />])
    }
  }, [result, projects]);
```

however, this solution would result in an infinite loop...

My suggestion would be to rework some of the logic and use `projects` to render your `Project` components, instead of creating a variable to encapsulate your render Components. Something like this:

```
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState();
  const { user } = useUserAuth();
  const dbRef = ref(db, `/${user.uid}/projects/`);

  useEffect(() => {
    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      setProjects(snapshot.val());
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {projects.length > 0 && projects.map(project=>{
        var projectData = {
          title: projects[key].title,
          description: projects[key].description,
        };
        return <Project props={projectData} />
       })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're component is not re-rendering since react doesn't care about your `result` variable being filled.

Set it up as a state like this: `const [result, setResult] = useState([]);`

Then use map to return each item of the array as the desire component:

```
{result.length > 0 && result.map((data, index) => <Project key={index} props={data} />)}
```